# Pull SVN trunk to a git branch

Tags: git, svn

I sometime fork SVN repos in GIT. When the SVN repo is updated I would like to be able to easily merge SVN changes doing a git merge.

The ideal would be to be able to have the SVN repo trunk in a GIT branch so I can sync the SVN branch and then merge from it.

Is such a layout possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best [using `git-svn`](http://progit.org/book/ch8-1.html) and `git-svn dcommit` to keep a Git Repo in sync with an svn repo.

Then you can start a Git branch on top of that imported SVN trunk in your Git repo, and benefit from merges after the `dcommit` (ie after importing SVN changes into the Git branch dedicated for reflecting SVN revisions).

Comment: You pointed me to a nice and comprehensive how to. Thank you.